# heroku run rake db:migrateを実行してもデータが入らない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

初心者です。

質問させて頂きます。

データベースはpostgresqlを使っています。
rubyは2.0.0　Rails 4.2.1です。

ローカルサーバ上ではデータが入っていて正常に表示されるのでデータベースにはデータが入っていると思うのですが、pushしてheroku上でデータが入っているか確認するとデータが入っていません。

heroku run rake db:migrateを実行すると下記のような文章がでます。
特にエラーではないので問題ないように思うのですが、データが入りません。

教えて頂けると助かります。

ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git push heroku masterしてもローカルにあるデータはアップロードされません。
PG Commanderなどでローカルのデータをアップロードするか、csvなどでデータを保存してcommitしておいて、rake db:seedを使いheroku上でseedするなどが良いと思います。